# firebase listeners don't work on Mobile data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on real time tracking app, we use firebase database to read/write locations, it was working fine, but lately It doesn't work on mobile data at all, I've searched here and read multiple threads about this issue but there is not enough information about it.

I've tested it on many device, it's the same behavior, firebase doesn't read/write on mobile data, when switching to wifi everything is ok.

Does anyone has the same problem and found a solution to such case?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Im experiencing the same

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not a programming problem. You said it was working fine previously. So - in your device go to Settings - Apps - 'your app' - Data usage. Make sure you have switched Mobile data on and you do not have the data limiter exceeded.